# why Event code: 4011 is shown as information

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have an error with permission to access a folder.

Event code: 4011 
Event message: An unhandled access exception has occurred.

However in the event log, it shows as information rather than Error. Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: But who puts it into an error log in first place - is it your own logging code or reporting by ASP.NET/IIS7

Comment: it is reporting bu ASP.net/iis7

Comment: i have the same problem, did you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is years after your question was posted but I had this error and fixed it. It seems to be a problem with a corrupted app pool. Restarting the server didn't fix it but creating a brand new app pool for the site worked.

Comment: created new app pool and assigned it but same error

Comment: I just had the same issue. I solved it by giving the IIS user permissions to read and write to the affected folder.